# MapView does not show proper point

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mapkit

I have just started to use MapKit framework, and my first practice did not go well  :)

Everything seems to be works fine except MapView showing somewhere in ocean and it did not find any place (ex: Land, island). I think latitude and longitude getting out of range somehow.

here is my code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIBarButtonItem *zoomButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
     initWithTitle: @"Zoom-In"
     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
     target: self
     action:@selector(zoomIn:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *typeButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
     initWithTitle: @"Zoom-Out"
     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
     target: self
     action:@selector(zoomOut:)];

    NSArray *buttons = [[NSArray alloc]
                        initWithObjects:zoomButton, typeButton, nil];

    barButtons.items = buttons;



    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);

    MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

    zoomLocation.latitude = 48.431638;
    zoomLocation.longitude= 27.169436;
    annotationPoint.coordinate = zoomLocation;
    annotationPoint.title = @"My Company";
    annotationPoint.subtitle = @"my Company Title";


    //[self __mapView];

    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [__mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];

    [__mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

    [__mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `zoomLocation` coordinates after creating region. Try first to set `zoomLocation`

```
...
zoomLocation.latitude = 48.431638;
zoomLocation.longitude= 27.169436;
MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE, 0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);
MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
...
```

Comment: But i have another problem now , which is :

    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (zoomLocation, 600, 600); doesn't show proper zoom at first start ...

Comment: Did you track user location?

Comment: I want to track user's location, I mean when user change his position, I want to get current position and  fetch them with services ...